# Custom rules for sutime (Stanford Temporal Tagger)

Tags: stanford-nlp, sutime

I've been trying to add custom rules to SUTime and I'm stuck with one of them. I've tried various approaches and none of them seem to get the result I want.

```
5 - 8 years returns the following.

{
    'text'  : '5 - 8 years',
    'type'  : 'DURATION',
    'value' : 'P5Y/P8Y'
}

5-8 years return the following. (no space between the hyphens)


{
    'text'  : 'years',
    'type'  : 'DURATION',
    'value' : 'PXY'
}

This is my understanding
- '5-8' and 'years' are the tokens it produces
- 5-8 is not mapped to anything and therefore is not considered relevant
```

What I've tried:-

```
These are results on running them on '5-8 years'

{ text: /(\d+)[-](\d+)[\s]+($TEUnits)(s)?/ =>
    Duration( TIMEUNIT_MAP[Lowercase($3)], $2) }

    gives 'value': 'P8Y' as expected. I want 'P5Y/P8Y' as the value.
```

- I tried various composite rules but finally got closest to the solution only by using the above mentioned text rule.
- I tried using various form of Duration like `Duration( $1, $2, TIMEUNIT_MAP[Lowercase($3)] )`, `Duration( $1, $2, TIMEUNIT_MAP[Lowercase($3)], TIME_UNKNOWN, TIME_REF )` and many other  combinations even if they didn't make sense. They all resulted in the rule being ignored and therefore gave the same result.
- I tried cleaning the data by replacing (digit-digit) by (digit - digit) but that led to problems in detecting dates.

### Gist

How do I get value tags of the form `P5Y/P8Y` from the text `"I've been reading from the last 5-8 years"`?

I've put an honest effort and have gone through most of the rules file, accompanying documentation and 3 other Stack Overflow questions several times. I also got three other rules to work.